# Angular8: Email Verification when new user registers

Tags: angular, email, laravel-5.8, angular8

i want to implement email verification whenever new user register/signup. I am using Angular from front-end and Laravel from back-end. what is the best approach to achieve that and How??? Hope you will help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i want to mention one more thing here. I already have a register and login functions in controller in backend.

Comment: just create  a token in backend and send it to the email along  with the email as a clickable  url for example verify : `http://sample.com/verify-email/some_token` and in angular create a route for the same `/verify-email/:token` then get the token from `routeparams` and send it back to backend through an api call to verify the same also  add a google recaptcha as next step to prevent bot attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify it both front and back.

In front you can use this https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

In back... I aren't an expert in PHP but you can use this https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99

Comment: thanks Dani. its email verification not validation and I think Email verification can only be done from backend.

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose we have **component.html**   [Using angular material2 UI framework].Here, You are free to choose any framework to implement this.

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="email" required>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">[[getErrorMessage()]]</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


 @Component({
     selector: 'form-create',
     templateUrl: './component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./component.scss'], 
 })
 export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

   email   = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

   sampleForm = new FormGroup({
                      email  : this.email,
                         ..........
   });

   getErrorMessage() {
        return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
            this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
    }


 }
```

Above provides all kinds of validation on FE itself.  We can modify **getErrorMessage()** to show custom error message coming from server side.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but Anil i am talking here about email verification not validation. I already did that.